# confidence interval for median of an exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-function

I am having a hard time finding the confidence interval of the median of an exponential distribution. I am currently studying for an upcoming test.

I found the mle of $\lambda = \frac{5}{61}$

I solved $S(t>z)=0.5$ and found the median is $z=\frac{\log(2)}  {\lambda}$

Now I need to find the 95% confidence interval. I am unsure of how to do this. My first thought is to try something like:

$$
CI = \frac{\log(2)}{\lambda}
     \pm 1.96\sqrt{Var\left(\frac{\log(2)}{\lambda}\right)}
$$
where $\lambda$ is the mle I found above.

Is that how you correctly solve for the CI for the median? If so, how do I find $Var(\frac{\log(2)}{\lambda})$ ?

EDIT: i solved for 5/61 by maximizing the log-likelihood function. I am dealing with discrete data that is subject to right censoring

I would greatly appreciate someones help, thanks!

Comment: It seems that this question is missing some information. Where does the $\frac5{61}$ come from? Generally the concept of a confidence interval arises in the context of sample data...

Comment: i solved for 5/61 by maximizing the log-likelihood function. I am dealing with discrete data that is subject to right censoring.

Comment: i didn't bother inputing all the data because it is irrelevant at this point in order to find the confidence interval. I just would like some assistance on how to take the median and mle i found to create a 95% CI @Math1000

Comment: Context is useful. I'm not saying you have to explicitly list 5000 data points if that's how many you had, but the information in your first comment does seem relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Math1000 have I clarified the question enough? Are you able to assist me?

Comment: Yes, it is more clear what you are asking now. I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

For a sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ from an exponential distribution with unknown (rate) parameter $\lambda$, the sum $S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistic.
Moreover, this has a Gamma distribution with parameters $n$ and $\lambda$.
For $n = 5000$, the normal approximation should be quite good.

That Gamma distribution has mean $\mu = n/\lambda$ and standard deviation
$\sigma = \sqrt{n}/\lambda$.  So we have $ \mu - c \sigma \le S \le \mu + c \sigma$ with probability $0.95$, where $c \approx 1.96$.  Since 
$\mu \pm c \sigma = (n \pm c \sqrt{n})/\lambda$, this translates to a 95\% confidence interval for $1/\lambda$ of $[S/(n + 1.96 \sqrt{n}), S/(n - 1.96 \sqrt{n}]$.

Note that the median of the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is
$\sqrt{2}/\lambda$. So the confidence interval for the median is
$[\sqrt{2} S/(n + 1.96 \sqrt{n}), \sqrt{2} S/(n - 1.96 \sqrt{n})]$$

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to compute $\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{\log 2}\lambda\right)$, that would just be
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{\log 2}\lambda\right) = &\log^22\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac1{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right)
\end{align}
(where the $x_i$ are i.i.d. $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ random variables. Now, we compute for $x>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k }\leqslant x \right) &= \mathbb P\left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \geqslant\frac1x \right)\\ 
&= 1 - \mathbb P\left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\leqslant \frac1x\right).
\end{align}
Now, the some of $n$ i.i.d. $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ random variables has $\operatorname{Erlang}(n,\lambda)$ distribution, that is, if $X= \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ then the distribution function of $X$ is
$$F_X(t) = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}(\lambda t)^{k} e^{-\lambda t} $$
(this may be proved by a by induction with a somewhat tedious computation). Setting $t=\frac1x$, we have 
$$ \mathbb P\left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \geqslant\frac1x \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}\left(\frac\lambda x\right)^n e^{-\frac\lambda x}, $$
and so $$\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k} \sim \operatorname{Erlang}\left(n,\frac1\lambda\right)  $$

But I don't recognize the form of this distribution, and my eyes started to hurt as I computed the derivative to see if I might recognize a density...so I will advise that you defer to @Robert Israel's answer.

By the way, we generally are more interested in the asymptotic variance, i.e. the behavior of the sample variance as $n\to\infty$, than the exact variance which I computed above.